# adding or modifying the contents of an app after publishing it?

Tags: android, google-play-services

i want to publish an android app in the play store, the app should notify the users of any news or a new promotion. How can i add and modify the contents of app after being downloaded by users?

Comment: You can use Push notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a notification section of your app that grabs content from a web url. It would be fairly easy to grab some xml and display it however you want on your app.